# Discord Js getting API error while interaction.reply();

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am newbie to discord.js.I am trying to send back ephemeral after user clicked button. But I got the following error while calling interaction.reply() method. How to solve this error? Thanks you so much for your solutions.

Here is the code

```
client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
  
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

    if (interaction.customId == "not_robot") {
        if(interaction.member.roles == "999698015277297694"){
            interaction.member.roles.remove('999698015277297694');
            interaction.member.roles.add('1002943646355701830');
            console.log("role added");
            interaction.deferUpdate();
        }else{
            console.log("you're done");
            interaction.deferUpdate();
            interaction.reply({ content: 'Pong!', ephemeral: true })
        }
            
    }

});
```

This is the error which i got

```
C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\Builders' Cafe\bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:287
        throw new DiscordAPIError.DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\Builders' Cafe\bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:287:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\Builders' Cafe\bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:99:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\Builders' Cafe\bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\REST.cjs:52:22)
    at async ButtonInteraction.reply (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\Builders' Cafe\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:110:5) {
  rawError: {
    message: 'Interaction has already been acknowledged.',
    code: 40060
  },
  code: 40060,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1002951707334021140/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTAwMjk1MTcwNzMzNDAyMTE0MDpVNE1NSTR1eUs5TGlRZElZMW8xeTJoa3BhZWw2Zzk4UFJKWk9ZdnM1cllJYVZVdHlhYVhpUks3SGRDSWNoZHhDT3Z2aURidFl5WThMaTdZTXd3dDhpZFp5SWdyQUMyRUJkNlVYM0RHRHZFRUw4TElCbThpejZoeWE3NW43MkdyNQ/callback',
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: 'Pong!',
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: undefined,
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: 64,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Discord.js official guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#deferred-responses), you may be able to use `deferReply()` to trigger the `Bot is thinking...` message and also acts as initial response.

In order to deliver the final reply to your user, you must `editReply()`, and not send another reply, as this will cause the error `Interaction has already been acknowledged.`

For you, this is how it may work:

```
// Discord.js v13 and posterior

client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
  
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

    if (interaction.customId == "not_robot") {
        if (interaction.member.roles == "999698015277297694") {
            interaction.deferReply();
            interaction.member.roles.remove('999698015277297694');
            interaction.member.roles.add('1002943646355701830');
            interaction.editReply("Role added!");
        } else {
            console.log("You're done!");
            interaction.deferReply();
            interaction.editReply({ content: 'Pong!', ephemeral: true })
        }       
    }
});
```

Comment: @jfdifajdsfpiojdsaopfjdsaofkpia may I ask what Discord.js version are you using? You may need to continue using `deferUpdate()` instead of `deferReply()`. I wrote `deferReply()` because that is the new method that is being used on v13 and v14.